# Latent Semantic Analysis and Stemming

Tags: nlp, svd, lemmatization, lsa, latent-semantic-analysis

Assume a very large corpus of any inflective language. Does the following make sense? By applying LSA on such corpus, words with similar concepts converge together in vector space, thus inflected word forms reffering to the same concept should ideally be identical with their lemma in the space. With such assumption, any lemmatization or stemming of queries or corpus is not necessary. Or am i totally wrong?

Comment: It all depends - given the way LSA is generated (via SVD) the contextual similarity that is captured by LSA, or word2vec like methods won't work unless you have enough data (to capture the contextual information) for each word form.

Comment: Then, theoreticaly speaking, with text data of infinity size, LSA could achieve the task -- there is no theoretical (and simple and naive; if put put aside troubles with dimensions going to the ifinity) constrain why it shouldn't work?

Comment: Yes, with "infinite" text, this should do a reasonable job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the founders of LSA, [stemming is not necessary](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Latent_semantic_analysis). Though, I think there is general disagreement in the literature about this. I have read a few papers where stemming was found to improve results for a given information retrieval task.

Generally, there is [recent research](https://mimno.infosci.cornell.edu/papers/schofield_tacl_2016.pdf) that shows stemming does not help in topic modeling and may even hurt topic coherence.